# Jquery and Prototype Conflict in Rails Production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe to submit payments - it has been working in development and production, but after pushing recently I noticed there is a javascript conflict, which prevents stripe from creating the stripe key and processing the payment.

I have a problem I cannot seem to solve - I am using both jquery and prototype, and understand to use the below to avoid the conflict:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

I have removed most of the console bugs, but one remains that I cannot remove:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachEvent' application-adc689800dc4b504f7b6a94f201ed3c1.js:268
m application-adc689800dc4b504f7b6a94f201ed3c1.js:268
(anonymous function) application-adc689800dc4b504f7b6a94f201ed3c1.js:268
(anonymous function) application-adc689800dc4b504f7b6a94f201ed3c1.js:268
```

This points me to application.js, which includes the following:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require prototype
//= require prototype_ujs
//= require effects
//= require dragdrop
//= require controls
//= require_tree .
```

Does anyone have some suggestions on things to try?  Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: no cristal ball, sorry

Comment: Yes, use prototype or jquery but not both. They do the same thing.

Comment: Can you find the offending code in that file and post that. Also make sure you run `noconflict()` immediately after jquery is loaded

Comment: I ended up just removing prototype to avoid the issue all together - thanks, though.